# align 4 fields inline with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a form that have some horizontal and inline fields, found the best way instead fighting with the form classes just try to do it like another regular template,  I am able to place the label and fields next to each other but they are not taking all the possible space, and touch eachother,  I would like to be able to use all the space of the row,

this is what I have:
thanks guys

this is the gap I want to remove, I kinda cheeted and played with the div margins but I don't think that's the proper way to do it =(
[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    i want the birthday portion to be all one line all next to each other.
    using all the space like the Name field above, should i use some kind of <span>?

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="birthday" class="control-label">Birthday:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you might have to remove the padding on the `col-*` classes for that. Modified the answer to show the same.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `.col-xs-3` to have 4 equal columns on all screen sizes. Using `.col-lg-3` will only create the columns on large screens (≥1200px). Otherwise, it will collapse to show one on top of the other.
Also, to remove the gaps in between the the three inputs, you will have to remove the padding on the `.col-*` classes.

```css
div.col-xs-3 {
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}/*Just as an example. You might not want to this for ALL .col-xs-3 classes. You can modify this just for the input divs*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="birthday" class="control-label">Birthday:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't put in on the css, did it on the element, thanks,  and is possible to aligne the 3 fields to the birthday label as well? like if was all just one line?  at least for now that is all I need =) thanks.

Comment: found it,   row no-gutter  and removing padding 0    will do the trick,  thanks again =)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code I changed a few things to achieve the situation you want. I removed some rows because you simply did not need all of those.
Bootstrap rows adjust your grid, causing a difference in the width of your form fields.

I ended up writing the following code for you:

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <label for="birthday" class="control-label">Birthday:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
        </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

If you also want 'Birthday' above the inline fields you can change the classes to these:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <label for="birthday" class="control-label">Birthday:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for putting the example on how to put the birthday in one line and the rest below! that was cool.